# unable to open the link format with luanchUrl() (messenger, WhatsApp) - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to open messenger and WhatsApp using `launchUrl()` method from the URL_Launch plugin but every time i try the browser opens and show this message:

```
The webpage at intent://user/562084722.?intent_trigger=mme#intent;scheme=fb-messenger;package=com.facebook.orca;end could not be loaded because: net::ERR_UNKOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

this is the code :

```
//Call Directly
  _directCall() {
    launchUrl(Uri.parse('tel:00962785522213'));
  }

  //Open WhatsApp
  _launchWhatsapp() {
    launchUrl(Uri.parse("https://wa.me/+962797809910"));
  }

  //Open Messenger
  _openMessenger() {
    launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://m.me/amr.al.shugran'));
  }

  //open email
  _openGmail() {
    final Uri emailLaunchUri =
        Uri(scheme: 'mailto', path: 'info@athaddak.com', queryParameters: {
      'subject': 'Inquiry',
    });

    launchUrl(emailLaunchUri);
  }
```

the direct call and gmail are working fine, but whatsApp and messenger shows the error above so am not sure what format i should use to make it works, ill appreciate any help.

note: if i put for example "https://google.com", it opens without any issues. also if i use the old method `launch()` it also works with messenger and WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure you androidManifest.xml file
check this URL
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

example

```
<!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
<queries>
  <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: actually the "sms" and "tel" are working fine only whatsapp and messenger so i believe it could be the link format

Answer (score 0):

For messenger you should add this to your manifest file:

```
<queries>
        <provider
            android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider"
            android:exported="false" />
    </queries>
```

Comment: it actually didn't work the package installed on this emulator is com.facebook.orca not katana, so i tried both and it still show the same error so i believe it has something to do with the link scheme or format